# If I add a column to a google sheet thats connected to big query will the big query external table get the new column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, external-tables

I have a bigquery table that is connected to a google sheet link. I am going to add an additional column to this google sheet and wanted to know if the bigquery table schema will change to match? If not, do I have to completely recreate and link to the google sheet again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new column will not add automatically.

Instead of recreating the table though, if you open the table, navigate to the Schema Page, there will be a Edit Schema button which will allow you to add the new column with the desired data type.
[The Edit Schema Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp0SF.png)

Typically you only need to recreate the link if you change the order of column headers or remove a column.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).